# Is there a way to skip the evolution animation?

Tags: pokemon-go

If a lucky egg is used, then the XP can be doubled for 30 minutes, and some players use that to evolve Pokemon during that time to double their XP increase.

But the animations takes time... and it can take 25 to 30 seconds per Pokemon to evolve, so 30 minutes will mean roughly 60 evolutions.

Is there a way to make it faster?  Otherwise 2 lucky eggs will need to be used if more than 60 evolution is needed. (and also will need to look at how Pidgey evolve for 40, 50 times).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your device and network quality, restarting the Pokemon Go app right after tapping the Evolve button may be faster than the animation.

[One reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t5cn0/is_there_a_way_to_skip_that_animation_while/d62105s) claims the app restarts on their Samsung Galaxy S7 in "~8 seconds" which is faster than the evolution animation.

Comment: You misread the post. This method requires you not to restart your phone, but rather, your app. On my Nexus 5x, I can restart the app in 10 seconds if I'm on a good wifi connection.

Comment: @Schism ah so I did, let me edit my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: interesting... I wonder if Niantic might detect how come you can evolve so fast and ban you suspecting you cheat by a bot or script, or... actually another way might be using 2 devices (say iPhone and iPad) and both log in and evolve side by side, then maybe we can achieve double the speed

Answer (score -2):

One method, if your device is rooted, is to speedhack the game with a tool like sbgamehacker or Game Guardian. You could also reload the game depending on your connection speed and latency.