# How to restart Pokemon Go faster?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a known way to restart Pokemon Go faster?  I'm running on an iPhone, and plan to restart the application as a way to bypass the evolution animation.

Before evolving (several times with a lucky egg), I plan to restart my phone (so there less background memory being used), then turn off extraneous functions (Bluetooth, etc), and ensure I have a solid wifi connection.  Anything else, map caching?  Any iPhone specific tricks?

Comment: I'm curious, why the down votes?  This is in reference to the previous post about skipping the evolution animation: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284439/is-there-a-way-to-skip-the-evolution-animation

Comment: your question is asking about hardware usage of iPhones, which would be off topic, as this is a site about gaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly doubt that the way you are doing it will be faster then animation, but you should be using this method to close down the app, as opposed to a full reboot.

[Force Close an application for iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330):

> 1. Double-click the Home button to see your most recently used apps.
> 2. Swipe right or left to find the app that you want to close.
> 3. Swipe up on the app's preview to close the app.

Comment: Thanks, I never mentioned a full reboot.  I plan to restart the app by closing and launching as described in the link you provided.

Comment: Oh cool, they way you worded it kinda sounded like you intended on doing it that way. You map loads post login, so assuming fast wifi you look set.